# Serve static assets from 2 folders using Webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Express to serve content from 2 static dirs

```
app.use('/static', express.static("blossom"))
app.use('/static', express.static("public"))
```

Also using Webpack to run my server with these scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base static/ --history-api-fallback",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && node server.bundle.js",
    "build:client": "webpack",
    "build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server"
},
```

A typical link to a file in my HTML looks like this, which is fine in a production environment, but `404` when running the webpack-dev-server with `npm start`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/highlight.css" />`

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ] : [],

    output: {
        path: 'public',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Been messing around with it for a while now, but how can I run my webpack-dev-server whilst serving from my `/static/` virtual directory as well? Tried to set the `publicPath` of the `output` to `/static/` as above, but no luck.

Comment: have you tried the copy webpack plugin ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin